# Will you ever need the dragon claws again?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Are the various dragon claws that are found in Skyrim all a one-time use? I've been holding onto them just in case but is this necessary?  Will you ever need them after opening the door or are they expendable?

Answer (score 2):

Besides opening the puzzle doors and featuring in a [couple](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden_Legend) of [quests,](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bleak_Falls_Barrow_(Quest)) the claws have no purpose.

If you sell one, merchants will apparently [keep the item around](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Claws) in their inventories permanently.

However, as I'm always afraid of glitches and loathe to part with anything unique, I typically hang on to them, and stow them in a chest in my house.... just to be on the safe side.